# Codificacion Erronea en TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me esta ocurriendo un tema curioso con un TextBox en Windows Forms.
Utilizo un formulario de windows para encriptacion y desencriptacion de cadenas, el caso es que he visto que si en el TextBox escribo un caracter "\" internamente guada dos!
Por ejemplo si introduzco 12\\34 me encripta:
[image]
el valor que se guarda internamente en el textbox es
12\\\\34
[image]

¿Existe alguna manera de evitar que el control TextBox realize este tipo de comportamiento, es decir, que muestre en pantalla el valor real que contiene la propiedad .Text y no sus valores "escapados"?

Answer (score 2):

Es una cuestión de como se representa "el texto que se guarda internamente".

En los literales de String/caracter, la representación de la cadena `\` es `\\`, pero eso no significa que haya dos barras; es porque `\` es un carácter de control y siempre va asociado al caracter siguiente (`\n` es salto de línea, `\"` es el caracter `"` -para evitar que el compilador lo confunda con el fin del literal de String-, y `\\` es el caracter `\`).

El depurador/inspector simplemente te muestra la misma representación, como si fuera un literal (nota que añade las comillas al inicio y al final, que tampoco son parte del valor introducido).

Una comprobación de lo que digo sería mostrar la longitud del texto con el que estas tratando (en tu ejemplo, saldría 6 y no 8).

Comment: Cierto, el problema que tengo es que cuando al cliente se le pida que ponga la cadena de conexion a encriptar lo pondra de la forma "Server={0}\\WinCC;Database={1};..." y no quisiera andar diciendole que solo ponga una \. ¿Te suena si aparte del caracter \ hay algun otro que tenga este comportamiento?, la solucion que se me ocurre es quitar la mitad de los \ que se encuentren en la cadena.

Comment: El último comentario no lo entiendo. Lo que ponga el cliente en el TextBox será lo que pase a la variable, tal cual. Cuando se use para una conexión (o cualquier otra operación), ése será el valor. También para mostrar en pantalla (repito, lo que ves es la representación *en el depurador*; si lo muestras por pantalla o consola no duplica la `\\`). Si el cliente pone el dato mal, entonces es una cuestión de validación de la entrada, por ejemplo mediante una expresión regular; yo suelo preferir poner la validación y avisar al cliente de un error antes que cambiar el valor que pone sin avisar.

Comment: Si, al final he probado lo que me indica Marc en la respuesta de abajo y me funciona validando la entrada. gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

La solución a tu problema es usar el método `Replace` poniendo otro carácter que no sea '\' por ejemplo '/':

```
//A la hora de encriptar reemplazamos los '\\' por '/'
txt_destino.Text = AESThenHMAC.encripta(txt_origen.Text.Replace('\\','/'));

//A la hora de desencriptar lo hacemos a la inversa
txt_origen.Text = AESThenHMAC.desencripta(txt_destino.Text).Replace('/','\\');
```

De ésta forma obtienes siempre la cadena con los valores que tu quieres sin que interfieran los que añade el código para distinguirlos de los caracteres normales.

Comment: Tu solucion me ha servido de base, al principio parecia que iba bien, pero mirando en detalle, la solucion correcta es unicamente poniendo unicamente en la parte de desencriptar lo siguiente: .Replace(@"//", @"\");

Comment: Si solo quieres desencriptar si, pero si quieres hacer las 2 cosas necesitaras ponerlo en la otra tambien, ya que el resultado te lo va a devolver con el caracter cambiado, es decir, si el usuario manda a encriptar 12\\24 tu vas a enciptar realmente 12/24, y el resultado de desencriptar va a ser 12/24, por lo tanto, tendrás que hacer de  nuevo el replace del '/' por '\\' para que el usuario vea el texto que ha introducido correctamente.

Comment: @Veelicus También he modificado hace rato la respuesta porque me había dado cuenta de que había colocado algo mal, revisalo de nuevo si es así.

Comment: Hola, realmente como me funciona es en programa que realiza la encriptacion dejarlo todo normal, sin replaces ni nada y en la parte de codigo que asigna el resultado de la desencriptacion, en ese caso realizar el replace como he puesto .Replace(@"//", @"\")